# Drinking water tap mechanism: safe variety of silicone grease

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, lubrication

I have a tap that won't turn on properly, and I'm going to attempt cleaning the mechanism as per the tutorial video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8D-NhReAXY.  One of the steps in the process involves lubing the mechanism with silicone grease.  This tap is likely to be used at least for teeth-cleaning, and possibly also for drinking water.  Is there a particular variety of silicone grease that's safe for this purpose, or will any silicone grease do?

(For regulatory and product-availability purposes, I'm in the UK.)

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: Are you also worried about any corrosion ie minerals in the water pipes?

Comment: There are probably food grade greases, but for the very tiny amount you would be exposed to, there might be other stuff in the water/air/food that is more concerning, that you don't know about.

Comment: @SolarMike Good question.  I guess lead or aluminium salts would be a worry, iron or copper salts would not.  I've not been able accurately to determine the age of the house - local council has a planning application that looks like it's it in the late 1960s, but the ownership history in the deeds only goes back to the late 1980s.

Comment: added screenshot from video for clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are in the UK following applies.

In the video the plumber is using the Hight Tack silicon grease.

The High Tack is WARAS approved product for use in drinking water plumbing.

You can read more here

[WARAS](https://www.wrasapprovals.co.uk)

Answer (score 4):

In the US, searching for "food grade silicone grease" (grease, not oil/liquid, is key here) provides many options. A "Super" one that I am familiar with is only incidentally food rated -- I mostly use it to lubricate the inside of ratchets that I rebuild. Makes the mechanism smooth as butter :)

Looks like the usual US plumbing supply brands have their own food grade silicone grease in small containers at home improvement stores as well.

You should be able to find something easily in the UK. As a side benefit, try some next time you rebuild a ratchet, too. Loved the accent and British plumbing terminology in Hamish's video!

Comment: I think the best search term would be "potable water grease". I don't think you need to specify silicone, that search comes up with fluorocarbon-based greases as well.

Comment: @Ruskes Right, but I have no objection to answers useful to people in other jurisdictions.

Comment: @Ruskes and Armand is well aware of his location v the OPs location, gave examples of US based possibilities and indicated that similar options should be available in the UK, too. What's your point?